# Why does 012 return 10 in the console?

Tags: javascript

Why if I log `012` to the console, it returns 10? Or e.g. `0123` returns `83`?

```js
console.log(012);
console.log(0123);
```

Comment: if you want decimal value, you have to mention radix value.

Comment: Enable [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) to avoid this problem and many others!

Comment: To complement @SachinBankar's answer, do it with: `console.log(parseInt(012, 10))`